# Get TLS-Unique from SSL stream and process HTTP

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, iis

After long investigation I still didn't find way to get TLS-unique value (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5929) from SSL connection stream using WCF (whole communication using HTTPS protocol though).
We are not strictly tied to WCF, so I know there is a TcpListener that allows that via SslStream class, but we need also full support of HTTP processing, so I don't know easy way to further process that binary data from TCP that will support HTTP spec. Any help would be useful.

We are implementing [EST protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7030) that requires both HTTP and TLS-unique value processing.

Comment: Codeproject has a number of very good examples of SSL with full source code.  Here is one example : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL

Comment: Thanks for response, but the problem is when I read SSL data then I need to process request body as usual HTTP request. So it requires full-blown HTTP processing, including Keep-Alive support and so on.

Comment: You should get a cookie from the SSL and then use the cookie when sending the request.

Comment: I'm not sending, I'm receiving the request. It's HTTPS - HTTP body encripted by SSL. The problem is that EST protocol needs info from both layers simultaneously - TLS-Unique and client certificate from SSL and HTTP request path and body from HTTP.